# Generating text from different tables - Structural question w. illustration

Tags: java, database, postgresql, data-structures, dynamically-generated

I am building a quiz-ish application which dynamically creates a personalized result based on your answers.

There will be 4-5 different user variables combined with your answer on each question that decide your result. This means that there will be roughly 100 different "text snippets" that will be mixed and matched for the final result to display correctly.

I am having some trouble in how to implement this in practice and would need some guidance / experience from similar approaches.

The text snippets will be set and stored in the database table below named "Texts". These in turn will be marked with brackets (or "keys" ) to show which items are dynamically fetched. These items are either based on the user answers, the result or other text snippets.

Getting everything from the same table works great. It is a recursive function that gets all texts based on each bracket-key.

The problem starts when trying to get the keys & queries from another table, since it would be a super tedious task to mark all of these differently (i.e. `[identifier](table)` and also to map up which conditions in the "WHERE..." clause that would have to be filled.

I am looking for some pointers if I am thinking of this the wrong way, and/or if there would be an easier solution to the problem?

[image]

The flow in the image is as follows:

*1. The "loop" starts with the "get_full_result" identifier and gets the text value*

*2. The program scans through the fetched text value for [keys] within brackets*

*3. Here the dynamic fetching should occur, fetching some data from other tables, and some data from the same table (texts)*

*4. The user is presented with a readable result text*

Comment: You said getting everything from the same table works great. Okay, why not just go with that then? What is it about getting them from multiple tables that is super tedious?  It's not real clear what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is how to say to the program "Hey, don't look for this key in this current table - look for it in the User table". I can't store everything in the same table, since i need to separate the user entries, results & texts to not make the database a spaghetti hell

Comment: I think I understand. Can the same key exist in multiple tables?

Comment: And what happens if it does? Do you prefer one table over another?

Comment: The same key could technically exist in multiple tables, and perhaps do a priority order of Texts->Results->Users.

Comment: I was thinking of having a separate table called "text_keys" which every key would go through, that would then point to the correct table / column for that key, but it might be a bit messy to actually implement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189131/discussion-between-user2868900-and-willis-blackburn).